Appium accessibility id's different on android
I am trying to add testID's to my component so automated tests can be run.
I am adding the testId's like below. I have added some screenshots of the appium inspector, id for iOS and accessibility id for android are the same. How can I get accessibility id in the same format for iOS and android?
   <NativeTouchableOpacity
      testID={testId}
      accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
      ...
      {...rest}>
      {children}
      {icon && iconStyle && <View style={iconStyle}>{icon}</View>}
    </NativeTouchableOpacity>

My inspector has different 
enter image description here
